# Windows & Linux support for each other's file-systems

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems

Why if we open linux we are able to view windows file system but when we open windows we are not able to view linux file system unless we use some software?

Answer (score 6):

Because Linux uses a different file system and you need support from the operating system to be able to read the file system. Windows does not provide support -natively- for the typical Linux file system (ext3, ext2, etc). You can do this installing additional software, as you know.

Answer (score 6):

Because the Linux developers wrote support for Windows file systems, but not the other way around. You should complain to Microsoft if you want Linux FS support in Windows.

Comment: Not really, because we already have software at our disposal.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You need software to view either system. However, you already have software to see a windows system from linux (as linux reads the windows system), but you don't have any software to see the linux system (as windows by default doesn't come with that software)

Comment: The Linux kernel has built-in support for reading vfat, ntfs, gpfs, hpfs, ufs and cdfs from mbr, gpt and Windows dynamic disks. Unless you want to claim there is a significant portion of Windows systems running on exfat, I think you are wrong. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems)

Comment: @Eroen: Built-in only if you choose to enable it, I've seen many distros where you manually need to enable it so he's not wrong. It's not like we are all running on Ubuntu...

Comment: While I believe ext3 and cdfs are the only filesystems included if you do a `make defconfig` of Linux, the NT kernel should (in principle) run along happily without `ntfs.sys`. What parts of an unmodified Windows install are "Windows" and what is "software" is a bit blurry to me, but I'm of the opinion that anything contained within the release tarballs of Linux not marked as experimental *must* be considered part of the base operating system, at least when it provides required functionality.